# Как комбинировать массив под разный интервал?

Tags: php

Как комбинировать массив под разный интервал?

Исходный 5 минутный (300 секунд)

Нужно комбинировать под 15 минут, 30 минут, 1 час, 4 часа, 1 день

```
$times = [
  ['t' => 1666051200, 'd' => 5],
  ['t' => 1666051500, 'd' => 2],
  ['t' => 1666051800, 'd' => 3],
  ['t' => 1666052100, 'd' => 4],
  ...
];

foreach ($times as $time) {
  echo 'Time: 'Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time['t']) .', Data: '. $time['d'] .'<br>';
}

// Текущий результат
// Time: 2022-10-18 03:00:00, Data: 5
// Time: 2022-10-18 03:05:00, Data: 2
// ...

// Нужно получить такой результат, если под 15 минут
// Time: 2022-10-18 03:00:00, Data: 10
// Time: 2022-10-18 03:15:00, Data: 4
// ...

1666051200 => 2022-10-18 03:00:00
1666051500 => 2022-10-18 03:05:00
1666051800 => 2022-10-18 03:10:00
1666052100 => 2022-10-18 03:15:00
1666052400 => 2022-10-18 03:20:00
1666052700 => 2022-10-18 03:25:00
1666053000 => 2022-10-18 03:30:00
1666053300 => 2022-10-18 03:35:00
```

Comment: А, что значит комбинировать? брать из данных только те значения которые кратны 15 минутам 1 часу и т.д.? или время приводить к ближайшему интервалу? или суммировать что-то?

Comment: @Tunker, суммировать данные где время кратно 15 минутам

Comment: Наверно суммировать данные, которые попадают внутрь интервала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем дополнительные массивы и в основном цикле суммируем для необходимых интервалов

```
<?php
$times15=array();
$times30=array();
$times = array(
    array(
        't' => 1666051200,
        'd' => 5
    ),
    array(
        't' => 1666051500,
        'd' => 2
    ),
    array(
        't' => 1666051800,
        'd' => 3
    ),
    array(
        't' => 1666052100,
        'd' => 4
    )
);
foreach ($times as $time)
{
    echo 'Time: ' . Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time['t']) . ', Data: ' . $time['d'] . "\n";
    
    // формируем массив на 15 минут
    $begininterval15=intdiv($time['t'], 900) * 900;
    if (array_key_exists($begininterval15, $times15))
        $times15[$begininterval15] = $times15[$begininterval15] + $time['d'];
    else
        $times15[$begininterval15] = $time['d'];
    
    // формируем массив на 30 минут
    $begininterval30=intdiv($time['t'], 1800) * 1800;
    if (array_key_exists($begininterval30, $times30))
        $times30[$begininterval30] = $times30[$begininterval30] + $time['d'];
    else
        $times30[$begininterval30] = $time['d'];
    // Дальше по аналогии 1 час = 3600 секунд, 4 часа = 14400, 1 день = 86400
    
}
// выводим массивы
foreach ($times15 as $t => $d)
    echo 'Time15: ' . Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t) . ', Data: ' . $d . "\n";
foreach ($times30 as $t => $d)
    echo 'Time30: ' . Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t) . ', Data: ' . $d . "\n";
```

Результат:

```
Time: 2022-10-18 00:00:00, Data: 5
Time: 2022-10-18 00:05:00, Data: 2
Time: 2022-10-18 00:10:00, Data: 3
Time: 2022-10-18 00:15:00, Data: 4
Time15: 2022-10-18 00:00:00, Data: 10
Time15: 2022-10-18 00:15:00, Data: 4
Time30: 2022-10-18 00:00:00, Data: 14
```